# why does "SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.geeksforgeeks.org', port=443)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to build my first webscrapper in python, I have followed a tutorial, installed the right libraries and copied from the tutorial the exact text:

‘‘‘

> import requests
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> req =requests.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
>
> soup =BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
>
> print(soup.prettify())

‘‘‘

but python gives me this error all the time

---

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    440             try:
--> 441                 cnx.do_handshake()
    442             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1715         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1716         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1717 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1455         else:
-> 1456             _raise_current_error()
   1457 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py in exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
     53 
---> 54     raise exception_type(errors)
     55 

Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
    602 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    345         try:
--> 346             self._validate_conn(conn)
    347         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    849         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 850             conn.connect()
    851 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    325             server_hostname=hostname,
--> 326             ssl_context=context)
    327 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    328     if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
--> 329         return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    330 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    447             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 448                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
    449             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    439                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 440                     timeout=timeout
    441                 )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    640             retries.sleep()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.geeksforgeeks.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ed1606e0fa56> in <module>()
      1 import requests
      2 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
----> 3 req = requests.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
      4 soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
      5 print(soup.prettify())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     57     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     59 
     60 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    506         }
    507         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 508         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    509 
    510         return resp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    616 
    617         # Send the request
--> 618         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    619 
    620         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    504             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    505                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 506                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    507 
    508             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.geeksforgeeks.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Obvious suggestion: make sure your CA certificates bundle is up to date

Comment: On a more helpful note: update your requersts library with `pip install -U requests`, maybe restart your system, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. I used sometihing similar and worked. So, the problem seems to be a faulty configured webserver. Since you´re using anaconda, you can try this config. Found similar issue here "https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4930"

```
   conda config --set ssl_verify False
```